# Why does "Run-time error '6': Overflow" pop up when the long variable is within allowed range?

Tags: vba, integer, runtime-error, overflow

When I run the following code it gives me "Run-time error '6': Overflow" even if the variable is within allowed range according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/long-data-type):

```
Sub Test()
Dim a As Long
a = 4 * 10000
Debug.Print a
End Sub
```

If I replace 4 with long variable, it works fine:

```
Sub Test()
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
b = 4
a = b * 10000
Debug.Print a
End Sub
```

Or If I replace 4 with 3, it works fine again:

```
Sub Test()
Dim a As Long
a = 3 * 10000
Debug.Print a
End Sub
```

What is the reason of this?

Comment: I changed the [long-integer] tag for [integer], since in VBA a `Long` is a 32-bit integer, while in most modern languages that would be a 64-bit integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with this one:

> ```
> Dim a As Long
> a = 4 * 10000
> ```

`a` is a 32-bit integer, but the `4` and `10000` literals are 16-bit `Integer` literals.

Same here:

> ```
> Dim a As Long
> a = 3 * 10000
> ```

Except this time the result fits a 16-bit integer (max value being 32,767), so there's no overflow.

So why does this work then?

> ```
> Dim a As Long
> Dim b As Long
> b = 4
> a = b * 10000
> ```

Because now `b` isn't an `Integer` anymore - VBA knows it's a `Long`, and since it's multiplying with an `Integer` literal the result will definitely need to fit a `Long`, 32-bit integer.

---

Also try these:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(4)
Debug.Print TypeName(32767)
Debug.Print TypeName(32768)
```

Now these:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(4&)
Debug.Print TypeName(CLng(4))
```

And that:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(4), TypeName(4%), TypeName(4&), TypeName(4#)
```

---

#### TL;DR:

Any literal that's smaller than 32,768 is an `Integer` (16-bit) literal unless it's decorated with a type hint or explicitly converted to another type.

This won't overflow:

```
Sub Test()
Dim a As Long
a = CLng(4) * 10000
Debug.Print a
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Comment: @HappyForever FWIW type hints are quite heavily discouraged - prefer the conversion functions (e.g. `CLng`, `CInt`, `CDbl`, etc.) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The data type of result is usually the same as that of the most precise expression.

In the first example one of your literals is 4 which is an integer and the result of your operation is greater than 32,767 (highest possible value for an integer variable), which will give you an overflow error.

When you replace it with 3, your result is smaller than 32,767

When you use a variable then the most precise expression becomes a long integer and you would not have a problem